# Secondary bar with chart.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I am trying to make a chart as in the following image using Chart.js. The blue and red graphics are stacked and the black chart outline is a secondary axis graphic that lies behind them all.

[image: Chart 1]

All I could do is the chart below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
<script>
  var poteData = { myData };

  var poteOptions = {
    legend: {display: false},
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true, 
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        } 
      }],

      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true, 
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        } 
      }]
    }
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: poteData,
      options: poteOptions
    });
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a similar style by styling the bars and adding a second axis. Refer to the annotations in the below snippet:

```js
var poteData = {
  //myData
  labels: ['a', 'b'],
  datasets: [{
    data: [1, 2],
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    borderWidth: 15
  }, {
    data: [3, 4],
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    borderWidth: 15
  }, {
    data: [10, 11],
    backgroundColor: 'transparent', // style this bar appropriately.
    borderColor: 'black', // style this bar appropriately.
    borderWidth: 5,// style this bar appropriately.
    yAxisID: 'right' // assign this bar to the second y-axis.
  }]
};

var poteOptions = {
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  responsive: true,
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }, {
      id: 'right', // create a second y-axis called 'right'.
      position: 'right', // draw it to the right side of the chart.
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
}

//window.onload = function() {
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: poteData,
  options: poteOptions
});
//};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```